# Add a string to a uibutton title

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uibutton

I am trying to update the title of a button based on an string from an array the string nextplayername is working fine however im strugling to get the text after it to display.

```
 [self.shownextbutton setTitle:nextplayerName @"Your Up! " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Basically i want the button title to display the following "nextplayername string" Your Up!

Comment: First thing's first: change `Your` to `You're`

Comment: did you bother to google this before asking? this is a very simple thing to do and can assure you it is a part in many tutorials online

Comment: yes spent a few hours looking sadly didnt know what to look for tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
... setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ You're Up!", nextplayerName] ...
```

to create a string from your desired content using a format specification.

Alternatively, append the strings together:

```
NSString *title = [nextplayerName stringByAppendingString:@" You're Up!"];
... setTitle:title ...
```

Better, support localisation:

```
... setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ You're Up!", @"Batter up!"), nextplayerName] ...
```